# How to clear bitmap memory of previous activity when open new one

Tags: android, performance

My app has tons of bitmaps. I have tried everything from Android Dev training, but my app still has `OOM errors`.

My `activity A` has a listview which contains a list of images. When click it opens a new `activity B`.

`Activity B` has the details of that image and a list of recommend images. When clicked to list below it open new activity and so on...

I do everything to minimize the memory but app crash after open 6 - 8 activity. So anyone can help me how to clear bitmap memory of previous activity when open new one?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: try `bitmap.recycle()` on `onDestroy` of activity.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bitmap.recycle()` in your `onDestroy()`.

Also you can use this code in your `onDestroy()` to avoid `OOMExceptions`. This basically unbinds all images in your activity:

```
public void unbindDrawables(View view) {//pass your parent view here
        try {
            if (view.getBackground() != null)
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);

            if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
            } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
                    unbindDrawables(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

                if (!(view instanceof AdapterView))
                    viewGroup.removeAllViews();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have seen this advice quite often but normally this is not needed. Resources from an activity are automatically freed when you don't have references anymore. What you do here is to give the system an additional hint that the image can be recycled but that is also done without this explicit call. To me it sounds more like the reporter still has references.

Comment: @Carsten I am not sure if it's done automatically. I see my OOMS reduced to almost zero after adding this in onDestroy() of all my fragments. Ofcourse my app has only one activity and many fragments loaded in the same BaseActivity.

Comment: I was getting 100-200 OOMs everyday before this. But after updating my app with this, i see 1 or 2 a day. And my app has 10000+ users.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have any special flags on your activity in your manifest so it always opens a new instance.

You could use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your activity to make sure it is only loaded once. However I think that in your case it would be better to use fragments and hold the reference to your images only once.

Normally you get `OOM errors` when you do not free up the references to your images.
More details are difficult to provide without seeing the *code* that deals with the images.